# Is repeated dictionary access optimized in Python

Tags: python

Consider the following Python code, that iterates over an array of words and counts them into the dictionary `a['words']`

```
a['words'] = {}
for word in words:
    if word not in a['words']:
        a['words'][word] = 0
    a['words'][word] += 1
```

The question is, whether the repeated access to `a['words']` is optimized in Python, in a way that the reference of `a['words']` is automatically saved somewhere until changed, OR should I write myself the "optimized" code, this way:

```
a['words'] = {}
words_dict = a['words']
for word in words:
    if word not in words_dict:
        words_dict[word] = 0
    words_dict[word] += 1
```

Comment: No, it is not. Python cannot make these sorts of optimizations easily. There is no way the interpreter can guarantee that value will always be the same.

Comment: The good news is you could do: `a['words'] = words_dict =  {}`

Comment: I would use the second option - only you could use _collections.Counter_ to further simplify things

Comment: That's nice. But what you're saying is that Python will **not** track or assume that the value of `a['words']` is constant, and hence, **will** make the whole hash computation each time, just to get the dictionary at `a['words']`

Comment: That's another story but you could optimize it by using `collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)` and then avoid initialization for each word and directly use `for word in words: a['words'][word] += 1`.

Comment: How could python possibly assume that `a['words']` is constant when the value can easily change?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I agree that to "assume" is wrong. But it could trace it. I mean to the reference of course, not to the content

Comment: Tracing sounds more expensive/complicated than performing a dict lookup, which is pretty cheap after all

Comment: You realize, the interpreter does not know that `a` is a `dict`, and an expression like `a['words']` could work for any type that defines a `__getitem__` method, which could do anything

Comment: @Pawamoy _collections.defaultdict(int)_ would do the trick, _lambda_ is redundant

Answer (score 4):

Good solution is [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as it is high-performance container:

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'eee']
a = {'words' : dict(Counter(words))}
a
#{'words': {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 1, 'ddd': 1, 'eee': 1}}
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap `dict` around `Counter`, as `Counter` object is already a dictionary. `Counter` has some additional (possibly useful) methods not available in `dict`.

Comment: Thanks. The counter is just an example. My question is regarding Python code optimization (since the code is more readable and beautiful without assigning `a['words']` into a variable)

Comment: Anyway, nice to learn about `collections.Counter`. I really didn't know it before :)

Comment: @SomethingSomething you can see the implementation example of Counter [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/)

Comment: @jpp Though the `Counter` object is more useful I went with the format described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
for word in words:
    if word not in words_dict:
        words_dict[word] = 0
    words_dict[word] += 1
```

performs up to 3 dict accesses per loop. Even if access is `O(1)`, hashing is far from free, specially on string objects.

In that particular case `collections.Counter` is perfectly suited. For other cases (like creating a list or appending to it), `collections.defaultdict` is a good alternative, and it's faster. Fictive alternate example:

```
c = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,word in enumerate(words):
    c[word].append(i)
```

there's also the `dict.setdefault()` solution, if you want to avoid `collections` module.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible for an interpreter. So I am going to make a discussion on how to.

First we need to specify the question, correct me if I am wrong:

**Given a lookup action and a scope, if the result of lookup action isn't changed in this scope, interpreter should cache the result.**

Caching is just a piece of cake, so what really valuable to discuss are unchanged lookup action and scope.

As far as I know, the minimal scope in python is function block(actually I am not sure about it). But the unchanged lookup action scope can be just part of a function block. So in this case, in order to cache this action, a new scope which is useless most of time should be introduced into python's runtime.

---

Thinking in another way, could the unchanged lookup action be detected during compiling? I think... it might be possible. Pypy use JIT tech to optimize performance, especially in some loop block(for example, a http server). So maybe Pypy has already done this feature?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would not say that scope is enough, since the dictionary `a` could be passed to some other thread that might change the value in `'words'`. I was wondering whether Python detects repeating expressions and traces them, in order not to compute them each time they present, if possible